# NSLog not working when debugging an app extension

Tags: xcode, nslog, ios-app-extension

I just can't see any logs in the window, even though I know I'm attached to the extension, I can place and enter into breakpoints, as well I see the values of variables.

However I can't see any logs.

Any ideas?.

Normal app logs works just fine.

Comment: Are you running the correct scheme for your target ?

Comment: What do you mean by scheme?.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are running the actual main app, not the extension (wrong **scheme**).

In Xcode, next to the *play* and *stop* buttons it should say the name of your app and the device you're running on. Make sure it says the name of your extension, not the name of your actual app.

Please see the attached screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, I have selected my keyboard extension - not the main application 'TransKey'. Once you do that, you should be able to see the logs in the Debug area for your extension.

Comment: Tried this but doesn't work on Xcode 14